# Does ActionScript 3's specification use "frame" to mean the same thing as "scope"?

Tags: semantics

The [ActionScript 3 specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20171028212944/http://bloople.net/as3ls/) frequently uses the term "frame" within the verification phase such as in:

(1)

> Code inside a `with` statement will have a `with` frame as the inner most scope on the scope chain.

(2)

> Let frame be an empty activation frame

Is "frame" the same as "scope" in terms of the scope chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, *scope* tends to refer to regions of source code in which certain names/variables/symbols are available, and *frame* (or related terms like *stack frame* or *activation frame*, but the ActionSCript 3 specification appears to be making a distinction between "frames" and "activation objects") refers to a memory region or object that exists when the compiled code is being executed that keeps track of associations between names/variables/symbols and values.

So they are usually different but closely related concepts, *scope* being generally a concept discussed as part of the language design, and *frame* being a concept for discussing the implementation. As far as I can tell, the ActionScript 3 specification simply does not make a distinction between design and implementation in this case.